# How can I filter a Django_Table that display records from a Dict instead of a model

Tags: python, django, django-filter, django-tables2

I would like to know if there is a way to filter on field in a Django table that is created with a dictionary instead of with a Model.

I have a Model that has 2 properties:

```py
#models.py
class DeviceConfiguration(Model):
    device = models.OneToOneField(Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    config = models.JSONField()
```

In that JSON lives some structured data that needs to be proccessed before i can present it in a table (It contains a dict with lists with dicts that needs to converted to a list of dicts).

I have the following table that uses an Accessor to traverse my custom JSON:

```py
#tables.py
class RawConfigTable(tables.Table):
    hostname = tables.Column(accessor=A('system__hostname'))
    version = tables.Column(accessor=A('system__version'))
    interface = tables.Column(accessor=A('interfaces__name'))
    status = tables.Column(accessor=A('interfaces__protocol'))
    speed = tables.Column(accessor=A('interfaces__speed'))
    class Meta:
        attrs = {'class': 'table table-condensed table-vertical-center', 'id': 'dashboard_table'}
        fields = ('hostname', 'version', 'interface', 'status', 'speed')
        sequence = fields
        order_by = ('hostname', )
```

In the views.py the table gets instanciated with the proccessed JSON as per [documentation](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/table-data.html):

```py
#views.py
class RawInterfaceList(View):
    """Displays all the interfaces from all devices in table form"""

    def get(self, request):
        all_configs = []
        for device in Device.objects.all():
            config = device.deviceconfiguration.config
            input = {
                'system': config['system'],
                'interfaces': config['interfaces']
            }
            all_configs.append(proccess(input)) # This is the custom proccessing i was talking about
        
        table = RawConfigTable(all_configs[0])
        RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
        temp = list(filter(lambda item: (item
            .get("interfaces")
            .get("protocol")
            .find(status_filter)),table.data.data))

        return render(request, "plugin/raw_interfaces_list.html", {
            "table": table
        })
```

This renders the table just fine, and with RequestConfig the table becomes sortable.
I tried making a [FilterSet](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/usage.html), but because my Table doesn't have a Model in its Meta the default manager cannot be found. The following code is what i used:

```py
#filters.py
class RawInterfaceFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    hostname = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    interface = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    status = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    speed = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    class Meta:
        fields = ['hostname', 'interface', 'speed', 'status']

#views.py
...
f = RawInterfaceFilter(request)
return render(request, "nnn-backup/raw_interfaces_list.html", {
    "table": table,
    "filter": f
})
```

And i get back this error:

```
 File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_filters/filterset.py", line 192, in __init__
    queryset = self._meta.model._default_manager.all()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_default_manager'
```

I also tried to manually editing the table.data.data property before passing the table variable to the template renderer, but any changes get ignored/reversed.

Is there a possibility to filter these tables without using a Model directly as input for the table?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the mean time i found a fix by filtering the data before parsing it to the Table class, but i would still like a way to use Django_Filters...